# Android: Standard 'Next' Button and Background

Tags: android, button, background

How do i get the button styles of the standard next/previous buttons and the gradient backgrounds like in the image below

[image: next button]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> gradient backgrounds like in the image below

Hi, for gradient backgrounds you can apply below Background Drawable code.

Change color codes according to your needs !

Create gradientbg.xml and paste code given below,

```
<shape
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">

<gradient
    android:startColor="#817f81"
    android:endColor="#ccc9cc"
    android:angle="90" />       
</shape>
```

this will make gradient background that you need !

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Got it.. extracted both from the AccountsAndSyncSettings.apk :) Its part of the Android system, so i guess there shouldn't be any copyright issues right?

You can add the image to the button using `android:drawableRight` attribute of `<Button>`

[image: next button]

[image: titlebar]